# Delay render of a component for test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a loading component

```
import React from 'react';

import './Loading.sass';

const Loading = ({ message, pastDelay }) => {
  if (pastDelay) {
    return (
      <div className="loading-bro">
        <h1>{props.message}</h1>
        <svg id="load" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
          <circle id="loading-inner" cx={75} cy={75} r={60} />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default Loading;
```

This is rendered via `react-loadable` as so

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Loading from './components/Loading';

const AsyncRoute = loader =>
  Loadable({
    loader,
    loading: Loading,
    delay: 300,
  });

const Home = AsyncRoute(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './containers/Home'));

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

This all works perfect and I'm happy with it, however....

How do I test this?

I am using Jest / Enzyme, any unit tests around this component fail as the node is not rendered.

How can I test 2 cases, that it is rendered and that is is not depending on the time to paint?

Comment: I'm going to give you a perhaps unpopular opinion: *You don't*. The tests that you're looking for—e.g. 'expect a certain component is rendered until a certain time is reached and then replaced with another component'—is the functionality of `react-loadable` and certainly is more than covered by their test suite (we'd hope). You can only expect to test your own business logic—for example, you could test that AsyncRoute returns an instance of Loadable, etc